# Create frame wih both single and multi-level columns and add data to it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-level

I have 2 dataframes like this

```
frame1=pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])


a=['d1','d2','d3']
b=['d4','d5']
tups=([('T1',x) for x in a]+
  [('T2',x) for x in b])

cols=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tups,names=['Trial','Data'])
frame2=pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
```

My goal is to have both DataFrames in one, and then add some rows of data. The resulting DataFrame would be like

```
  Trial    A   B   C        T1         T2
  Data                  d1  d2  d3   d4  d5
0          1   2   3    4   5   6    7   8
1           ...     
...
```

That could somehow be achieved if I did

```
frame2['A']=1
frame2['B']=2
frame2['C']=3
```

But this is not a clean solution, and I can't create the frame and then add data, for I would be required to at least insert manually the first row.

I tried

```
frame3=frame1.join(frame2)

>>  A1   A2   A3 (T1, d1) (T1, d2) (T1, d3) (T2, d4) (T2, d5)
```

This I think is not multi column level.
My second trial

```
tup2=([('A1',),('A2',),('A3',)]+[('T1',x) for x in a]+
  [('T2',x) for x in b])
cols2=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tup2,names=['Trial','Data'])
data=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
frame20=pd.DataFrame(data,index=cols2).T 

 Trial  A1  A2  A3 T1       T2    
 Data   NaN NaN NaN d1 d2 d3 d4 d5      
0        1   2   3  4  5  6  7  8
```

This one works fine when trying to query it `frame20.loc[0,'A1'][0]` but if for example I do

```
frame20['Peter']=1234
>Trial  A1  A2  A3 T1       T2      Peter
 Data   NaN NaN NaN d1 d2 d3 d4 d5      
0        1   2   3  4  5  6  7  8   1234
```

being the column 'Peter' what I desire as opposed to for example A1, which is what I get.
My third trial

```
tup3=(['A','B','C']+[('T1',x) for x in a]+
  [('T2',x) for x in b])
cols3=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tup3,names=['Trial','Data'])
frame21=pd.DataFrame(data,index=cols3).T
```

returned exactly the same as the second one.

So, what I'm looking for, is a way to do

```
pd.DataFrame(rows_of_data,index=alfa).T  #or
pd.DataFrame(rows_of_data,columns=beta)
```

where either alfa or beta are in a correct format.

Also, as a bonus, let's say I finally came up with a way to do

```
finalframe=pd.DataFrame(columns=beta)
```

How do I have to use `concat`,`append` or `join` so I can add a random row of data such as `data=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` to my empty but perfectly created finalframe?

Thank you, best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add a level to `frame1` with empty strings

### `pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples`

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(c, '') for c in frame1])
f1 = frame1.set_axis(idx, axis=1, inplace=False)
frame3 = pd.concat([f1, frame2], axis=1)

frame3.reindex([0, 1])

     A    B    C   T1             T2     
                   d1   d2   d3   d4   d5
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

---

### `pandas.concat`

```
frame3 = pd.concat([
    pd.concat([frame1], keys=[''], axis=1).swaplevel(0, 1, 1),
    frame2], axis=1)

frame3.reindex([0, 1])

     A    B    C   T1             T2     
                   d1   d2   d3   d4   d5
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: I find your answer usefull, but let's say you have that final dataframe frame3. How would you add a new row from a list?

Comment: Use `append`.  `frame3.append(pd.Series(mylist, frame3.columns), ignore_index=True)`